# Change the src of an iframe

Tags: jquery, ajax

Trying to change/modify the source of any/all iframe on the page where the src includes youtube.com, and get the video id from the src url.

Here's what I have so far that's not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
changeYoutube();
function changeYoutube()
{
    $('iframe').each(function() {

   var that = $(this);
   var href = that.attr('src');

   if(href.search('youtube.com') != -1) {      
      that.attr('href', href+'&autoplay=1');
   }

});
});
```

I also need to put the video id from the url into a var.  Example url:
    http://www.youtube.com/embed/hP9rBDYYFvw?fs=1&feature=oembed
Where "hP9rBDYYFvw" is the video id in that url.

Thanks

Comment: Assume that no iframe's on the page have id's.

Comment: What exactly is "not working"? Are you getting JS errors?  Have you tried debugging it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeYoutube() {
        $('iframe').each(function () {

            var that = $(this);
            var href = that.attr('src');

            if (href.search('youtube.com') != -1) {
                that.attr('src', href + '&autoplay=1');

               // code to get id

                    var tmp = href.split("?");
                var tmp2 = tmp[0].split("/"); 
                var ID = tmp2[tmp2.length - 1];
            }

        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        changeYoutube();
    });
  </script>
```

First You have set the href attribute but you must set src attribute of iframe. Second You must first define the function that You call after document ready, and in Your code you haven't close the function. Best Regards.

Comment: That did the trick.  Any ideas on the second part of the question about the video id?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up.  I also found this in the meantime `var videoId = href.split('/')[1].split('?')[0];` which works for me also.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one closing brace **`}`**.

Replace last line **`});`** with **`}});`**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    changeYoutube();
});

function changeYoutube() {
    $('iframe').each(function() {
       if($(this).attr('src').search('youtube.com') != -1) {
          var href = $(this).attr('src');      
          $(this).attr('src', href+'&autoplay=1');
       }
    });
}
```

it's just another style from yours. perhaps it works..please try

Comment: I'll test it and report back.

Comment: That did the trick.  Any ideas on the second part of the question about the video id?